# Mobile Home Light

Tags: wiring

What do i need to do to add a light with two wires (outside backdoor light) to the existing inside the door hall light switch that has a hot, neutral & ground wire, it is the only wire going into the switch, so its hot from the breaker. The trailer has aluminum wiring. and I have some 12/2 Romex to add the 3' piece of wire from the switch to the light.

Comment: Are you sure about aluminum wiring? How old is the trailer? That may complicate things quite a bit.

Comment: Why do you say there is a neutral wire at the switch?  Because it is white?   Do you have access to the inside the door hall light? What's in there?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question?